# codename one - no way to set background image in list

Tags: list, background-image, codenameone

I am new to codename one and I have tried for one and half day to fix my issue of,
a list with background image in **each row**.

Let me explain, I am having a list with some items(entries), I created renderer and name it appropriately. I set background correctly which is reflecting in designer (see image)

[image: theme is not reflected in simulator nor on real device]

but when I run it on **simulator/device** , all formatting and designs are just invisible..!! (see red arrow pointing to simulator in image)

anyone have any idea ? why this is happening ?

Thanks,
Akash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you didn't set the background correctly in the designer. Since the list items in the model within the designer are strings the renderer entries don't get overriden and so you see a separate UI.

To reproduce the issue in the designer click the items entry in the list property, remove everything and add a sample key/value hashtable pair. You would see all your design entries disappearing.

This might help you understand how to customize images and backgrounds here: http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/12/deeper-in-the-renderer.html

Comment: unfortunately I didn't get clue to set custom BG for list from link

FYI code is

`code`
.initListModelListInstances(List cmp) {
        cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(getInstanceList()));
        return true;
    }
.
Vector getInstanceList(){
Vector vec=new Vector();
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
h.put("Line1", "Wildwing Demo Instance");//I assure that Line1 
h.put("Line2", "VIS2_tornado");//& Line2 are name in rendererList
vec.addElement(h);
return vec;
}
`code`

See link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wptgdojge3fabts/instanceScreen.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5v1pb8vau179hnt/renderlist.png

Comment: Those are unrelated to background, background comes from the UIID which you define to the renderer. You should then add styles in the theme section to customize the background.

Comment: sorry I dumb didn't find any damn example to set list background in codename one.  
here is flow of what I did:  
  
1)I created component in theme named **MyContainerWithImage** and set BGImage:seems perfect in designer  
2)I created renderer named **rendererList** with container and 2 label in container  
-Set **UIID to MyContainerWithImage** for rendererList container so each row seems with image  

3)In my screen GUI I added **list** and **set its renderer to rendererList** which shows me list as per my expection BUT in designer only, in device its not working?  
  now please tell me

Comment: after creating rendererList and setting it to list do I need to modify anything ?

  
I am setting model as
..
cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(vec));
..

is it correct?  

I am asuring that I am assigning data in vector by Hash-table and with exact name used to declare component (label) in designer

Any guidance will be very helpful or any video to set custom background in list is more appreciated..

Thanks
Akash

Comment: Can you update your screenshots to a version with properly fixed key/value pairs and place screenshots of the property UIID's/styles you used?

Comment: thanks for continuous support, I like this very much about codename one.  

 here is my screenshots..

[image 1: component: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jhgvkqperhdbj1/err1.png ]  

[Image 2: renderer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jhgvkqperhdbj1/err1.png ]

[Image 3: screen where I am using list: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmeaybi90jogqf8/err2.png ]

[Image 4: My code and simulator screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8l8f5mitm55y46w/err3.png ]

Please let me know if I miss any thing  

 Thanks you for sparing time for me..  
 Akash

Comment: I don't see how this doesn't work. Just creating a simple hello world app this worked instantly see the app here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57067724/Renderer.zip

Comment: thanks for code, I'll look into that and try to compare it with my mistake/s and let you know..

Comment: thanks again for demo code..
finally I realized that my theme was overwritten by my own attached library..hence it was not having design effect..but it was reflection only text change..
Any way..now its working..
Many thanks for your time and suggestions..
Best regards,
Akash